# How to write the family of sets whose elements are the sets in a sequence of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am wondering, given a sequence of sets $( X_n )$, how do we write the corresponding family of sets whose elements are the sets in the sequence?

Of course, the same question applies to nets as well.

Any feedback is welcome.
Thank you for your time

PS: I am not completely sure how correct is the tag "notation" in this context.

Comment: I usually write $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, whereas $\{\,X_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\,\}$ would be the set of the sets occuring in the sequence (and the family). - Then again, "sequence" and "family" (with index set $\mathbb N$) are essentially the same concepts ...

Comment: I see, but if we take the functional analysis approach, a sequence is something like $( X_n )$ (note the round braces), thus they are not really the same, right?

Comment: For me both are the same as the third: a function with domain $\mathbb N$. Whether we call it function or sequence or family (and use different notations accordinly) is matter of taste or a means to emphasize one aspect or other of the same thing.

Comment: I see, but how if you take $(X_n)$ as a sequence, how do you talk about an element of it? We can write $X \in \{ X_n \}$, because it concerns sets, but we cannot really use the same notation to talk about an element of a sequence.